# Open my application from Calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm trying to open my android application from calendar event using CUSTOM_APP_URI.

1. So i insert an event to Calendar through my application.
2. Opening Calendar app, and navigating to the event details.
3. Clicking on the event URI, my app should open from calendar events details page.

Here is the code i used for inserting the events into calendar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginCal.set(2015, 11, 10, 4, 30);
    long startTime = beginCal.getTimeInMillis();

    Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCal.set(2015, 11, 10, 4, 30);
    long endTime = endCal.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Check Demo Calendar4");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTime);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI, "calendar://1");

    getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

Calendar displaying the ever perfectly but Problem is even after inserting the event doesn't show the URI  in my calendar event's detail page. 
What is wrong inserting the vent with CUSTOM_APP_URI? Any help?

Comment: Anyone can you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @Ravi did yout resolved? Because i'm stuck on your same problem

Comment: facing the same issue seems a dead end

Comment: I have this problem too. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not all calendar apps support the `CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE` field. To my knowledge only the following calendar apps have that feature:

- AOSP Calendar app
- Google Calendar
- aCalendar
- CalenGoo

The last time I checked, neither Samsung's calendar app nor HTC's calendar app supported it.

If anyone is aware of other calendar apps that support the `CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE`, please add them.

Also, make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` contains the correct `intent-filter`, see [ACTION_HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#ACTION_HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code hope it helps:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("your_activtiy_package_name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: I didnt get. How this will work. This piece of code for starting my activity. But where to write this code?

Comment: This code will open your application and you have to write this code where you want to open your app.

Comment: I want to open my application from the device's built in calendar application. How can i write this code over there? :)